# Why my Reg Exp in ga:filters is changed in the final request?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on a GA-API stuff and I found the tool:
http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
very useful.

But when I copy the Reg Exp into my own code as follows:

```
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': lastNDays(30),
    'end-date': lastNDays(0),
    'metrics': 'ga:visitors',
    'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
    'sort': '-ga:visitors',
    'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~/q-\d+/.+',
    'max-results': 50
  }).execute(handleCoreReportingResults);
}
```

I can't get any result.

I found that 
  `filters: "ga:pagePath=~/q-\d+/.+",`

is changed to
  `filters: "ga:pagePath=~/q-d+/.+"`

The `\d` becomes `d` and I failed to get what I want.

Why the `\` is just gone? Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aw**, looking at the [filter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference), I would suggest escaping the backslash. So technically, you would end up with double backslashes:

```
"ga:pagePath=~/q-\\d+/.+",
```

See the linked page, section *Filter Expressions*:

> Reserved characters — The semicolon, comma, and backslash must all be
>   backslash escaped when they appear in an expression.

Hope this helps.